# Теория синтаксического анализатора

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, лексический-анализатор

Прошу вашей помощи, потому что не могу до конца разобраться с синтаксическим анализатором.
При первом прохождении файла набор символов разбивается на лексемы и заносится в таблицу.

Следующим шагом должно быть разбиение лексем на классы (мне нужно отличить идентификаторы в паскале).

Как отличить идентификаторы от не идентификаторов?
Выполнять проверку на на принадлежность к определенной множеству зарезервированных слов (операторов и т д)?

При разбиении на классы нужно использовать дерево. Как я не понимаю.
На первом уровне должны быть типы лексем?
Каждым элементом кроны должен быть определенная лексема, которая встречается в коде?

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Классификация лексем зависит, конечно, от языка.

Для начала, идентификаторы паскаля начинаются с буквы, поэтому вы их никак не спутаете с операторами.

Конкретно для паскаля есть фиксированный набор идентификаторов, которые опознаются как *ключевые слова*. Так что получив идентификатор, просто проверяйте, нет ли его в списке.

---

Рискну предположить, что под "деревом" для классификации лексем подразумевается следующая конструкция:

Лексема -- это либо идентификатор (начинается с буквы и содержит буквы, цифры и знак подчёркивания), либо скобка, либо оператор, либо знак пунктуации.

Идентификатор -- это либо ключевое слово (список прилагается), либо имя.

Скобка -- это либо круглая скобка, либо квадратная (фигурные выбросил препроцессор), может быть открывающей и закрывающей.

Оператор -- это один из списка (плюс, минус, ...)

И так далее. Видите дерево?

Comment: IMHO в дальнейшем трансляция выражений упрощается, если вместо типов *круглая скобка, квадратная скобка, оператор плюс, оператор умножить и т.п.* ввести единый класс ***операция*** и в таблице операций определять и характерные для нее свойства и общее свойство операций - приоритет.

--

Конечно от задачи зависит. Может ТС нужно просто список имен переменных, встречающихся в комментариях для каждого исходного файла сделать. Тогда все заморочки с операциями просто не нужны.

Comment: @avp: угу, я иногда так и делал. Хотя если применять lex/yacc, [обычно](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/flexbison/) лучше всё же по отдельности.

Answer (score 8):

Самый простой способ получить пару лексический/синтаксический анализатор на практике сгенерировать его автогенератором из БНФ грамматики языка с помошью Flex и Bison (lex и yacc). Если хотите написать самому нормальный парсер курите теорию конечных автоматов и формальных языков. Если пытаться интутивно писать его, то с вероятностью 99% после первой попытки получится медленная, плохо-читаемая конструкция состоящая из условных переходов и сравнений строк чуть менее чем полностью. При этом сама эта конструкция на самом деле будет являться кривой реализацией конечного автомата для данной грамматики, но написавший её может даже  и не подозревать что это так.

Вот пример уже готовой lex и yacc грамматики для Паскаля. Всего 1000 строк кода.

- [scanner.l](http://code.google.com/p/toypasc/source/browse/trunk/scanner.l);
- [parser.y](http://code.google.com/p/toypasc/source/browse/trunk/parser.y);

P.S. Если захотите скомпилировать эту грамматику под Windows стоит брать flex.exe bison.exe из Cygwin или MinGW, а не с сайта GNU там почему-то лежат старые версии.

Comment: Считается, что это правильно. 

Правда, Страуструп в "Дизайн и эволюция С++" пишет, что если бы ему пришлось делать компилятор еще раз, то он выбрал бы ручное написание синтаксического анализатора.

Вообще в использовании генераторов масса подводных камней.

Comment: @avp: грамматика C++ не LALR(1), так что без трюков её на lex/yacc не распарсить. Пример:

    ident ident '(' ident ')' ';'

можно распарсить и как предварительное объявление функции, и как объявление переменной с вызовом конструктора.

Comment: @avp: да и паскаль грешит shift/reduce-конфликтом: в

    if (expr) then if (expr) then statement else statement

`else` может относиться к любому `if`'у. В спецификации языка сделано произвольное решение: к ближнему.

Comment: @avp @VladD по моему основная проблема не в том чтобы распарсить грамматику уже готовым алгоритмом, а в том чтобы придумать ее и дальше совершенствовать полученный таким образом компилятор, вводить различные оптимизации, поддержку разных платформ, соответствие стандарту, стандартную библиотеку и.т.д и.т.п.

Comment: @igumnov: мне почему-то кажется, что топикстартеру покамест нужны не оптимизации, а хорошо работающий ручной парсер.